# Why in HMS Awareness first item of getHourlyWeather() gives different results?

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services

in HMS Awareness, When I am using **getHourlyWeather()** to get weather details of 24 hours,the first item (index 0) gives different results? I am little confused that if it gives the details of current hour weather details or previous hour weather details?

Adding the code which I used here

```
 WeatherStatus weatherStatus = weatherStatusResponse.getWeatherStatus();
                    List<HourlyWeather> hourlyWeather = weatherStatus.getHourlyWeather();
                    weather_info_capture.setText(""+hourlyWeather.get(0).isDayNight());
```

Comment: What do you mean "different results"?

Comment: By Different result I mean  it is pointing current hour or previous hour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call the getWeather() method , the Awareness service checks whether the cache has been used for more than one hour. If yes, the Awareness service will fetch the latest weather infomation and update the cahce and return. If no,it will return the cache infomation.
For example, there is no cache. You call the method at 16:50. Awareness service fetch the
latest weather data, so the first item in the HourlyWeather list is the weather at 16:00. Then you call the method at 17:20 again. The cache is return because the weather cache exists and is less than 1 hour. Therefore,it seems that the first item is the weather data of the previous hour.